# unable to load data in chrome from mysql database using thymeleaf but in console getting query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, thymeleaf

````
**Flight.java**
```package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
@Entity
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity {

    private String flightNumber;
    private String operatingAirlines;
    private String departureCity;
    private String arrivalCity;
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;
    
    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }
    public void setFlightNumber(String flightNumber) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }
    public String getOperatingAirlines() {
        return operatingAirlines;
    }
    public void setOperatingAirlines(String operatingAirlines) {
        this.operatingAirlines = operatingAirlines;
    }
    public String getDepartureCity() {
        return departureCity;
    }
    public void setDepartureCity(String departureCity) {
        this.departureCity = departureCity;
    }
    public String getArrivalCity() {
        return arrivalCity;
    }
    public void setArrivalCity(String arrivalCity) {
        this.arrivalCity = arrivalCity;
    }
    public Date getDateOfDeparture() {
        return dateOfDeparture;
    }
    public void setDateOfDeparture(Date dateOfDeparture) {
        this.dateOfDeparture = dateOfDeparture;
    }
    public Timestamp getEstimatedDepartureTime() {
        return estimatedDepartureTime;
    }
    public void setEstimatedDepartureTime(Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime) {
        this.estimatedDepartureTime = estimatedDepartureTime;
    }
    
}```

**AbstractEntity**

```package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    
}```

**FlightRepository**

```package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.repos;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities.Flight;

public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight,Long> {

    @Query("from Flight where departureCity=:departureCity and arrivalCity=:arrivalCity and dateOfDeparture=:dateOfDeparture")
    List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from, @Param("arrivalCity") String to,@Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);
    
}```

**FlightController**

```package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.controllers;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities.Flight;
import com.shahbaz.flightreservation.repos.FlightRepository;

@Controller
public class FlightController {

    @Autowired
    FlightRepository flightRepository;
    
    @RequestMapping("/findFlights")
    public String findFlights(@RequestParam("from") String from,@RequestParam("to") String to,
            @RequestParam("departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="mm-dd-yyyy") Date departureDate,ModelMap modelMap)
    {
        List<Flight> flights=flightRepository.findFlights(from,to,departureDate);
        modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flights);
        return "displayFlights";
    }
    
    
}```
**displayFlights.html**

```<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Flights</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Flights:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Airlines</th>
<th>Departure City</th>
<th>Arrival City</th>
<th>Departure Time</th>
</tr>

<tr th:each="flight: ${flights}">
<td th:text="${flight.operatingAirlines}"></td>
<td th:text="${flight.departureCity}"></td>
<td th:text="${flight.arrivalCity}"></td>
<td th:text="${flight.estimatedDepartureTime}"></td>
<td><a th:href="@{'showCompleteReservation?flightId='+${flight.id}}">Select</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>```
````

**application.properties**

*spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservation?

useSSL=false&serverTimezone=CET&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false

spring.datasource.username=root

spring.datasource.password=root

server.servlet.context-path=/flightreservation

spring.jpa.show-sql=true*

**I am getting query in console but output is not reflecting in chrome while sending request**

*Hibernate: select flight0_.id as id1_0_, flight0_.arrival_city as arrival_2_0_, flight0_.date_of_departure as date_of_3_0_, flight0_.departure_city as departur4_0_, flight0_.estimated_departure_time as estimate5_0_, flight0_.flight_number as flight_n6_0_, flight0_.operating_airlines as operatin7_0_ from flight flight0_ where flight0_.departure_city=? and flight0_.arrival_city=? and flight0_.date_of_departure=?*
**I am searching for data which is available in database also format of date is correct for dateOfDeparture**

Comment: You can not give a value to `from`, `to` and `departureTime`

Comment: I am passing the values :-from to and departureDate using chrome if i will not pass then how i will get flight availability between them from database.If u can elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Please change custom query in @Query annotation of findFlights method in FlightRepository

From

```
 @Query("from Flight where departureCity=:departureCity and arrivalCity=:arrivalCity and dateOfDeparture=:dateOfDeparture")
List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from,@Param("arrivalCity") String to,@Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);
```

To

```
@Query("from Flight where departureCity=:fromCity and arrivalCity=:toCity and dateOfDeparture=:departureDate")
List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String fromCity,@Param("arrivalCity") String toCity,@Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);
```

Basically, the idea is that, you need to use parameters of findFlights method to build custom query and not the ones in @Param annotation.

Comment: I am getting error after changing FlightRepository to  the one u suggested but now getting Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'flightController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'flightRepository';